# how to validate color code via regular expression

Tags: php

I going to validate color code via regular expression for example :

```
#fff : true
#ffffff : true
#fnnkdf : false
255,255,255 : true
255,255 : false
255,255,256 : false
```

Can you help me?

Comment: Just did a quick Google `"^#([A-Fa-f0-9]{6}|[A-Fa-f0-9]{3})$"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a try:

```
/^(#[A-Fa-f0-9]{6}|#[A-Fa-f0-9]{3}|([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5]),([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5]),([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5]))$/
```

PHP sample:

```
<?php print_r(preg_match('/^(#[A-Fa-f0-9]{6}|#[A-Fa-f0-9]{3}|([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5]),([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5]),([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5]))$/','256,123,123')); ?>
```

What this does is to check if the number is greater than 255.

Simply check with `\d{1,3}` or `[0-9]{1,3}` will make something like 999,999,999 return true.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
((\d{1,3},){2}\d{1,3})|(\#[a-fA-F0-9]{3,6})
```

http://regexr.com/3a0e9

Comment: thanks, I trying this : `preg_match('\d{1,3},\d{1,3},\d{1,3})|(\#[a-fA-F0-9]{3,6}', '#fff')` and this error returned : `preg_match(): Delimiter must not be alphanumeric or backslash`

Comment: You need to add `/` to the start and the end of the regex.